# Encrypt large files on flutter and access them only through in-app

Tags: android, ios, encryption, flutter, storage

I am developing a digital media app using **Google's flutter framework** which contains songs, movies and etc. The main focus is, these media content should be accessible only through the app and not by outside methods (eg: media players, file browsers).

Eg: A music file which was downloaded through the app should only be played within the app and not by any media player. In that case, there should be an encryption method which should be used to lock these files from outside world.

In this case, bigger files such as Movies should also be taken into consideration. The size of a file can be anywhere between **few kbs** to **2-3 GBs**.

What should be the better approach when solving this problem?

Is it to

- Store everything in a database after encrypting the bytes?
- Encrypt the entire file and still keep them in the form of "file"?

The downloaded data should also be able to be consumed quickly once the user requested for it. And once the consume is done, the file should be locked again from the rest of the world.

I am not sure if this topic is too broad but somehow I would appreciate it if anyone could provide me with something to start off.

Thank you.

Comment: This problem is literally impossible to solve - if the user is viewing the movie/listening to the song - then they already have the raw content.  You can make things more difficult by encrypting locally etc but at the end of the day, it can always be reverse engineered and accessed.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark It's acceptable that the raw content is presented when the user is consuming it. So at the end of the day, we can clear it off. But a problem I have is which is the better way to store them in the local storage?

Comment: Storing upwards of 2 GB in a database probably isn't wise - store them in a file and store a key to that file in the database.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Will try this method out.Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @SajadJaward did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SajadJaward did you find any solution please?

Comment: @SajadJaward did you find any solution for this?
Currently same issue i am facing.So please give me some solution regarding this issue.